# Is there any way to travel from Germany to Austria by train?

Tags: trains, germany, austria, covid-19

I am trying to travel to Austria from Brussels by train, and have conflicting information on the status of cancellations due to Covid-19.

According to Eurail, "all rail services from Germany to Austria are cancelled until further notice"
https://www.eurail.com/en/help/travel-disruptions/coronavirus-update

Yet, Deutsche Bahn and the 'trainline.eu' both allow me to book high-speed ICE trains across the border, just not the Nightjet trains. There are notices saying that there are delays/reduced services expected at the border, but it is not impossible to book like it is for other trains.

My questions:

- does this mean that it is still possible to take the high-speed ICE trains?
- if not, is there any other way that it is permitted to travel over the German border to Austria (e.g. by bus, coach or taxi)? Unfortunately driving is not an option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a rapidly-changing event. Have a read on the relevant governmental websites to answer your question. These will surely be correct, as well as up to date.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use the Deutsche Bahn to cross the border to Austria, you should check the [Deutsche Bahn](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/aktuell/index.shtml) site for known train interruptions

- no trains or busses to **Tirol** (western Austria)
- at present (2020-03-19) none for other areas inside Austria as final destination

Assume that this may change at any time.

Check eligibility to enter Austria

- at the moment you must supply an acceptable reason to enter

---

**Sources**:

- [Deutsche Bahn - Aktuelle Verkehrsmeldungen](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/aktuell/index.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

The official website of Deutsche Bahn lists the current interruptions due to corona (only in german, trying to change the language to english took me back to the main page):

https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/aktuell/index.shtml

According to this site, several trains between Germany and Austria have been cancelled, including the NightJet, but I assume that other trains are still running. Since the site doesn't mention ICE trains between Germany and Austria, I assume they are still running.

In case the trains stop running before you make it to Austria: If you are eligible to enter Austria, nothing should stop you from entering by taxi (or, taking a taxi to the german side of the border, crossing the border by foot, ordering another taxi to pick you up at the austrian side of the border) - but depending on how close to the border you can get by train this can be quite expensive.

I wouldn't count on buses or coaches: They have never been quite as popular as trains, and the one company that offered (more or less) regular coach services - Flixbus - stopped operations tonight due to corona.

Comment: Note that the situation is changing rapidly.  After the Polish border closed, there were 60 km traffic jams with 30 hour waiting times.  A taxi driver may refuse to cross the border under the present circumstances.